# необычная связь Entity OneToOne doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine2

Существует Entity в которой нужно реализовать связь `OneToOne`, но проблема в том, что связь между ними осуществляется по полям не являющимся ключевыми и их несколько.

```
class MyEntityOne
{

    protected $id;
    protected $pole1;
    protected $pole2;
    protected $pole3; 
    protected $myEntytyTwo;

}

class MyEntityTwo
{
    protected $pole1;
    protected $pole2;
    protected $pole3; 
    protected $pole4;
    protected $pole5;
    protected $myEntytyOne;
}
```

Связь между ними типа:

`SELECT * FROM MyEntityOne O LEFT JOIN MyEntityTwo T ON (o.pole1 = t.pole1 and o.pole2 = t.pole2 and o.pole2 = t.pole2 and t.pole5=1)`

Не нашёл в документации как лучше реализовать данную связь, буду благодарен за любые идеи.

Comment: [Как образец](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table), через @JoinTable, обратите внимание на `joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}` в примере. Думаю, это оно. Ведь Entity далеко не всегда соответствует таблице, таблица - уровень хранения данных, Entity - абстракция на порядок выше. Не?

Comment: @Igor Dyshlenko на сколько я понял данный пример работает только связи `Entity` по `id`

Comment: Ну, по логике примера `joinColumns` - это список объектов, указывающих, по каким полям производится связывание. Список - это точно не _исключительно одно_ поле, полей может быть больше. И, как ни крути, все они быть полем id не могут по определению. Надеюсь, `joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="field1", referencedColumnName="refField1"), @JoinColumn(name="field2", referencedColumnName="refField2"), ...}` не ломает картину мира?.. :)

Comment: Я не предлагаю готовый рецепт. Лично именно такую связку еще не использовал. Но Вы просили идеи. Это обсуждение на уровне идеи.

Comment: @Igor Dyshlenko Спасибо, попробую)